# Angular 2: defer component rendering until service asynchronously initializes

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app which I'd like to keep as lean as possible (traffic-wise) and load certain data sets (from API URL) only when it is required.

The service that is responsible for loading the data is passed to a ui component constructor as a dependency. The component template has many references to the service's properties and methods. I can initiate the data loading in the constructor, but since the loading happens asynchronously, the component is already rendered when the data arrives.

So, basically, I am looking for a way to defer the component rendering until the service is initialized with the fresh data loaded from API. Currently I have a basic route with component that checks if the service is initialized, and navigates to the final route when it has finished initialization. But this is not pretty because it requires two routes for one view.

Comment: Do you have any particular problems with using route resolvers for that? That's what they are basically for.

Comment: If you're using the router https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard is a good choice.

Comment: Yep, the route resolver was the way I finally solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this;

Let's say that you are getting the data from your async call like this:

```
this.myService.myAsyncCall().subscribe((res)=>{...})
```

inside this async call lets say you are assigning the response to a field of the component

```
this.myService.myAsyncCall().subscribe((res)=>{
    this.field = res.data.list;
})
```

and you don't want your template to get rendered until this data arrives so you can use an `*ngIf` inside your template:

```
<div *ngIf="field && field.length && field.length > 0">
  ...
</div>
```

This is just an approach. You can use the safe navigation operator(`?`) for smaller operations but since you haven't provided **any** info about your code, I have given a generic answer.

Comment: It's just `field?.length`.

Comment: @estus thanks. I just wanted to emphasize that `ngIf` could be used to combine `if`s. Maybe the OP is combining 2 async fields so it may be done like `field && anotherField`

Comment: @echonax I'd have to wrap the whole template in a div with `*ngIf`, because there are quite many instances where the data from the service are pulled. It's a service that provides text snippets in UI for the selected language.

Comment: @Passiday well you can either use it like this or use a resolver like people mentioned in the comments. What's the problem with using this one?

Comment: @echonax thanks, I'll test the both ways. I'm kind of not happy with wrapping the whole template just because one service that needs loading. I hoped to solve this in code only.